# Will other countries (all are AIs) act differently if you enter an era?

Tags: civilization-5-brave-new-world

In Civilization V: Brave New World, will other countries (all are AIs) act different if you enter an era? For example if you were to enter the renaissance (or whatever) era, would other countries reach that faster?
I know that developing nukes does something along those lines, but does reaching eras?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I did some research (Asked it on /r/gaming, post [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/1kldlo/civ_brave_new_world_quesiton/)), apparently it doesn't, if anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 2):

The AI will be more reluctant to provide Research Agreements with you if you are in a more advanced era, as the cost increases. They will often request that you give money, or a resource as well as the agreement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if getting a lead in tech causes other players to research faster, it doesn't.

Unlike many games, Civ V does not have a slipstream effect which makes it easier for a player who falls behind to catch up. In fact, the opposite is often true- a player with a strong position will often continue getting stronger.